# What is the difference/relationship between the gradient and the Jacobian?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

What is the difference/relationship between the gradient and the Jacobian?

I think it has to do with vectors/covectors, tangent spaces / contangent spaces, but I'm not sure what's going on. (A gentle and readable but thorough reference in addition to an answer would be appreciated too.)

Let $R$ be the real numbers.
Let $f: R^2 \longrightarrow R$ be a smooth function.
Let $p \in R^2$.

(The Jacobian is typically defined for (differentiable?) functions $f: R^n \longrightarrow R^m$, but just set $m$ to 1.)

Now the gradient is a vector field, whose value at $p$ is a (column) vector (in particular, *not* a covector):

$$\nabla f(p) := \left[{\partial f \over \partial x_1}(p) \ \ {\partial f \over \partial x_2}(p)\right]^T$$

(with the convention that vectors are column vectors and covectors are row vectors).

And the Jacobian $Jf(p)$ is the $1 \times 2$ matrix (or just the row vector, ie. covector? what's the rigorous difference?):

$$Jf(p) := \left[\left[{\partial f \over \partial x_1}(p) \ \ {\partial f \over \partial x_2}(p)\right]\right].$$

In particular, since the gradient and the Jacobian are just "transposes" (duals) of each other, when would you use one or the other? What's the point?

There are related questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053229/the-connection-between-the-jacobian-hessian-and-the-gradient), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336640/gradient-and-jacobian-row-and-column-conventions), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54355/the-gradient-as-a-row-versus-column-vector), but I'm hoping for more insights.

Comment: Calculus point of view: gradient is the Jacobian of a real function of two or more variables ($f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$). The difference is the name and the notation.

Comment: "... but just set $m=1$..." well, there you go, in the special case that $m=1$, the "gradient" and the "Jacobian" are formally identical.

Answer (score 5):

The gradient $\nabla f$ is usually defined for a scalar-valued function $f$ (with values in $\mathbb R$, say), whereas the Jacobian is defined for maps $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$.  Thus the Jacobian is a generalisation of the gradient.  A more substantive difference exists between the gradient $\nabla f$ and the differential $df$, the point being is that the differential is intrinsic, whereas the gradient depends on the choice of a metric.  In Euclidean space they can be thought of as being the same, but once one switches to a more general framework of manifolds, the difference becomes crucial.  For example, in defining the de Rham cohomology of a differentiable manifold, one must use the differential $df$ because the gradient is not defined on a differentiable manifold without introducing a metric, which is not always desirable.

Answer (score 3):

"Derivative", "gradient" and "Jacobian" are essentially the same. They all describe how your mapping $f(x)$ induces the linear mapping between tangent spaces $T_x\mathbb{R}^n\to T_{f(x)}\mathbb{R}^m$. It's just one is preferred over another when talking about specific dimensions:

- $n=m=1$: derivative
- $n>1,m=1$: gradient
- $m>1$: Jacobian

Whether to use row vectors or column vectors is mostly conventional, and it depends on how you want the matrix representation to be used in arithmetics. For example, a nice convention for the Jacobian is:
$$
Jf(x)=\left[\matrix{\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\
&\ddots&\\
\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}}\right]
$$
because this allows you to write
$$
f(x)=f(x_0)+Jf(x_0)(x-x_0)+o(|x-x_0|).
$$

---

Note that I use the word "describe" because derivative/gradient/Jacobian is generally considered as a scalar/vector/matrix field, not the mapping itself, but it can be used to represent the mapping (at least in Euclidean spaces; I am not sure about manifolds). The mapping between tangent spaces induced by $f$ is called the differential $df$ of $f$.

Comment: second bullet point is misleading. The gradient is also used to mean a vector (field) associated to $df$ using an inner product.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I carefully chose the word "describe". The gradient vector field can be used to compute the differential mapping using the inner product.